# Is it correct to use "would" in the context provided?

Tags: grammar, future-constructions, would

Is it grammatically possible to use both **"would come"** and **"was coming"** in the context below:

> Earlier, the temperature had fallen. And now clouds began moving in. I knew a storm  **would come/was coming.** Would it be a snowstorm? I woke up the next morning to see the ground all covered with snow. There would be no baseball practice today!

If only one or both options are possible in this context, please, give reasons.
Thanks

Comment: *I **knew** a storm **would** come* is the past tense of *I **know** a storm **will** come.* And *I **knew** a storm **was coming*** is the past tense of the alternative *I **know** a storm **is coming***, so they're both fine,

Comment: Idiomatically, the second versions are much more likely in most contexts - and that's *particularly* true in your exact context, where ***now*** refers to a point in past time. If you'd used ***then*** instead of ***now***, that might *slightly* favour the ***would*** phrasing - but that's a fairly complex issue, so let it pass.